# How do i swap my keys and values without it reading letter for letter?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have to read a text file and make it a dictionary, then swap those keys and values and write it back to a new file, I cannot import anything either, the issue I'm having is right now I end up with it turning my values into letter by letter instead of words.

my text file is this:

```
Cloth:Stitching
Leather:Stitching,
Blacksmith:Molding
Pottery:Shaping
Metalworking:Molding
Baking:Heating
```

This has been a struggle because I do not know why, but lists, dictionaries and tuples are something my head is not wrapping around.

I tried to write my code in 2 ways

1st:

```
with open('trial.txt', 'r') as f:
    fr = f.readlines()
    prof = {}
    for line in fr:
        key , value=line.strip().split(":")
        prof[key]=value
        profr = {}
        for key, values in prof.items():
            for value in values:
                if value in profr:
                    profr[value].append(key)
                else:
                    profr[value]=[key]
```

output:

```
{',': ['Leather'],
 'H': ['Baking'],
 'M': ['Blacksmith', 'Metalworking'],
 'S': ['Cloth', 'Leather', 'Pottery'],
 'a': ['Pottery', 'Baking'],
 'c': ['Cloth', 'Leather'],
 'd': ['Blacksmith', 'Metalworking'],
 'e': ['Baking'],
 'g': ['Cloth', 'Leather', 'Blacksmith', 'Pottery', 'Metalworking', 'Baking'],
 'h': ['Cloth', 'Leather', 'Pottery'],
 'i': ['Cloth',
       'Cloth',
       'Leather',
       'Leather',
       'Blacksmith',
       'Pottery',
       'Metalworking',
       'Baking'],
 'l': ['Blacksmith', 'Metalworking'],
 'n': ['Cloth', 'Leather', 'Blacksmith', 'Pottery', 'Metalworking', 'Baking'],
 'o': ['Blacksmith', 'Metalworking'],
 'p': ['Pottery'],
 't': ['Cloth', 'Cloth', 'Leather', 'Leather', 'Baking']}
```

2nd try which just removes `.items()` to resemble my old code that worked however that code did not read a text file:

```
with open('trial.txt', 'r') as f:
    fr = f.readlines()
    prof = {}
    for line in fr:
        key , value=line.strip().split(":")
        prof[key]=value
        profr = {}
        for key, values in prof:
            for value in values:
                if value in profr:
                    profr[value].append(key)
                else:
                    profr[value]=[key]
```

output:

```
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\code\Scripts\Menu.py", line 8, in <module>
    for key, values in prof:
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

What do I need to do to get the desired output of:

```
Stitching: Cloth, Leather
Molding: Blacksmith, Metalworking
Shaping:Pottery
Heating:Baking
```

An explanation or links to an explanation would be helpful. I have googled a lot though so I do not know if anyone would link something I have not seen yet.

Comment: One problem you have is that `trials.txt` has a mistake in it: `Leather:Stitching,` has an extra comma which will spoil your outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you could parse it directly to a `defaultdict` with `list` as the default value factory.

```
from collections import defaultdict

profr = defaultdict(list)
with open('trial.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        v, k = line.strip(', \n').split(':')
        profr[k].append(v)
```

The `defaultdict(list)` object behaves just like a dictionary, with the exception of when a new key is pass, it creates an empty list instead of raising a KeyError.

---

**However**, since you said you *cannot import anything*, you can replicate this behavior with the regular dictionary using the `setdefault` method:

```
profr = {}

with open('trial.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        v, k = line.strip(', \n').split(':')
        profr.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

with open('out.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for k, v_list in profr.items():
        v_str = ', '.join(v_list)
        fp.write(f'{k}:{v_str}\n')
```

The `setdefault(key, value)` method of a dictionary does the following:

- if `key` exists in the dictionary, it returns existing value
- if `key` does not exist, it adds `key`, sets the value to `value` and returns `value`.

So in your case, if the key does not exist, a new empty list is assigned to the value for that key; and the empty list is returned, allowing us to call `.append`.

But if the key already exists - in this case, with a list as the value - then the list is returned, also allowing us to call `.append`.

As your code reads each line of text, you can parse it directly to what you need.  In this case, since you are swapping the keys and values, then you can simply parse each line as a `value:key` pair, instead of the other way.  That is what this line is doing:

```
v, k = line.strip(', \n').split(':')
```

The value comes first, and the key second.  It is also cleaning up any extra whitespace and commas.

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't actually run your code. If you had you would see the syntax error first, then the parsing error.

Comment: Thanks, I was on my phone while writing it.  Fixed now.

Comment: Ok, that was a tremendous effort if it was just on your phone! (I had already upvoted you anyway)

Comment: this was as huge help thank you, i didn't know setdefault was so helpful since my classes didn't actually cover it

Answer (score 0):

At least for the second error you need to write `for key, values in prof.items():`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).